# Windows batch file renaming for batch rendering

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filenames

I have a number of files inside a folder that I am trying to run through a batch render command for command line rendering. The batch works, but I want to access the name of each file and set it as output name for the generated png file. Here is my batch command:

```
set process_dir=%CD%
C:
cd C:\solidangle\mtoadeploy\2016\bin
for /r %process_dir% %%f in (*.*) do kick -set defaultArnoldDriver@driver_png.RGBA.filename "C:\Arnold\batch\file_name.png" -l ../shaders -dw -v 4 -t 6 %%f
```

so for example in the path "C:\Arnold\batch\file_name.png" I want to replace the 'file_name' with the name of the file that is executed in order to produce that png file. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the render application you are using but I can suggest you the following way. 
Replace `file_name` with `%%~nf` in your example.

To learn more about this feature and other read help with

```
FOR /?
```